# Why is my UIView not rotating about the z-axis?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, storyboard

I'm trying to get my UIView to rotate about the z-axis in Swift. But for some reason, the rotation axis is not as expected:

[image]

```
    rotatedView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    rotatedView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
    rotatedView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(rotatedObjectWrapper.object.rotation, 0, 0, 1)
```

How do I get the UIView to rotate about the z-axis? Thanks.

UPDATE:
I investigated and realised that the rotation is around the z-axis when I use a Stepper element to control the rotation. For context, the delegate function `delegate?.didRotateObject` update `rotatedObjectWrapper.object.rotation` value.

Slider:

```
@IBAction func didChangeRotation(_ sender: UISlider) {
    delegate?.didRotateObject(to: Double(angleSlider.value))
}
```

Stepper (which updates by 0.1 radians):

```
 @IBAction func didChangeStepper(_ sender: Any) {
    delegate?.didRotateObject(to: Double(stepper.value))
}
```

I tried using some animation to change the rotation value, and it sort of rotates around the z-axis, while still having the weird rotation behaviour:

```
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
      rotatedView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(rotatedObjectWrapper.object.rotation, 0, 0, 1)
    })
```

Outcome:

[image]

UPDATE 2:
I'm trying this out:

```
        testView = CustomObjectView(image: UIImage(named: "black"))    
        guard let testView = testView else { return }
        testView.frame = CGRect(x: rotatedObject.position.x, y: rotatedObject.position.y, width: rotatedObject.width, height: rotatedObject.height)
        testView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(rotatedObjectWrapper.object.rotation, 0, 0, 1)
        rotatedView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(rotatedObjectWrapper.object.rotation, 0, 0, 1)
        print(testView.layer.frame)
        print(rotatedView.layer.frame)
        rotatedView.layer.frame = testView.layer.frame
        print(rotatedView.layer.frame)
        print(")))))))")
```

`testView` is still rotating correctly, whereas `rotatedView` is still rotating weirdly. The only difference between the two is that `rotatedView` is obtained from a dictionary as such:

```
guard let rotatedView = objectsToViews[rotatedObjectWrapper] else { return }
```

I'm trying a hackish way to set the `rotatedView.layer.frame` to be equal to `testView.layer.frame` but it's not working.

Comment: What happens if you turn off scale to fill?

Comment: It doesn't do anything different.

Comment: UPDATE: It seems like this behaviour is caused by the UISlider. The above rotation is caused by using a UISlider to change the rotation of an object. When I tried rotating it using other UI controls/animation, the rotation seems to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

This code rotates a view about the z-axis based on the value of a slider, you can run it in a playground:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyViewController : UIViewController {
    
    var viewToRotate: UIView!
    override func loadView() {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        let label = UILabel()
        label.frame = CGRect(x: 150, y: 200, width: 200, height: 20)
        label.text = "Hello World!"
        label.sizeToFit()
        label.textColor = .black
        viewToRotate = label
        
        let slider = UISlider(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 300, width: 300, height: 40))
        slider.minimumValue = 0
        slider.maximumValue = .pi * 2
        slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(updateRotation(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
        
        view.addSubview(label)
        view.addSubview(slider)
        self.view = view
    }
    
    @objc private func updateRotation(_ sender: UISlider) {
        viewToRotate?.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(CGFloat(sender.value), 0, 0, 1)
    }
    
    
}
// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
```

[image]

It's not clear why your code isn't working, since the transform is being set the same way, but it must be in some code that isn't in your question. What are the values you are passing in for rotation? Are there any sublayer transforms?

Comment: I think it has something to do with me storing the view in a dictionary. I have some auxilliary structure with type [Object: CustomView]. I obtain the view via this dictionary, and am modifying it (since it's a class object, it should reflect changes on the superview).

Comment: I can't see how that would affect it. The animation you show looks to me like the view is trying to fit its contents into a frame that is being altered by the transform. You shouldn't set or read the frame of a transformed view. You need to include the contents of the view in your question, or replace it with something like a label so that you can have a better idea of what is actually happening - a black square doesn't tell you anything about which way up it is or why it doesn't look right.

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let rotatedView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 50, height: 50))
    
    var angle = 0.0
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        rotatedView.backgroundColor = .red
        view.addSubview(rotatedView)
        rotatedView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
           rotatedView.contentMode = .scaleToFill

        _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1/60, target: self, selector: #selector(updateFrame), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        
       
    }


    @objc func updateFrame(_ timer: Timer)
    {
        angle += 0.1
           rotatedView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(angle, 1, 0, 0)
    }
}
```

Comment: This works if I want to animate the rotation. Apologies for the lack of context, as I mentioned in the comment above, I need to control the rotation using a UISlider.

Comment: the only thing you need is to send the value of UISlider instead of angle += 0.1 . if you couldn't do that, let me know to write the code for you as I can see someone has already implemented the code for you below. on that case you don't the Timer. I just have written the code in timer so you can see it in action, otherwise the solution is this.